# I do not find the version of LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I recently installed the Wubi version of Ubuntu12.10. I need to find the version of LibreOffice installed on my system, but I cannot find it anywhere.Who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to find out which version is to open a document, in the global menu goto

Help > About Libre Office

[image]

Comment: I found it. I have got version 3.6.2.2. What I would like to do is create a document like in MS Publisher. Can I do this in LibreOffice? I read that I have got to install LibreOffice4. But I think I cannot install version 4 from Software Center. Where did you find your version4 of LO? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This link will help you http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-libreoffice-40-in-ubuntu-1204.html  If your question has been answered can you please mark the answer as accepted.